# Making text come from the right

Tags: batch-file

I need text to come from the right like this:

```
A :   0
B :  10
C : 100
```

So it starts at the right side. And A,B and C need to be variables!:

```
echo A : %A%
echo B : %B%
echo C : %C%
```

Edit:

If you are going to down vote me tell me what I did bad.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  Is this in a file or just set in variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

    set "pad=          "
    set "a=1"
    set "b=10"
    set "c=100"

    set "a=%pad%%a%"
    set "a=%a:~-5%"

    set "b=%pad%%b%"
    set "b=%b:~-5%"

    set "c=%pad%%c%"
    set "c=%c:~-5%"

    echo A : %a%
    echo B : %b%
    echo C : %c%
```

The basic idea is to define or generate a pad string, concatenate the pad string and the value and then take the necessary length from the end of the concatenated string.